How to find costs to an integer program that maximize integrality gap
Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. For $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let
\begin{align} \text{ILP}(c) = \max \quad & c^\top x \\ \text{s.t.} \quad & x \in \mathbb{Z}^n \\ & A x \leq b \end{align}
be the optimal value of a solution of the integer linear program defined by $A$, $b$, and $c$, and let
\begin{align} \text{LP}(c) = \max \quad & c^\top x \\ \text{s.t.} \quad & x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\ & A x \leq b \end{align}
be the optimal value of a solution of the corresponding LP relaxation.
I am interested in the problem
\begin{align}
\max \quad &\frac{\text{LP}(c)}{\text{ILP}(c)} \tag{MaxGap} \\ & c \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
i.e. finding costs $c$ that maximize the integrality gap.
I think this would be called a non-linear, bilevel optimization problem.
I tired to reformulate this problem as an mixed integer linear program and I got the following:
\begin{align}
\max \quad & g \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & g \geq 1 \\
& c \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
& g \cdot i \leq l \\
& l \leq \text{LP}(c) \\
& \text{ILP}(c) \leq i \enspace .
\end{align}
The inequality $l \leq \text{LP}(c)$ can be reformulated as $l \leq c^\top x$ with additional variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and additional constraints $Ax \leq b$.
The inequality $\text{ILP}(c) \leq i$ can be written as $c^\top y \leq i$ for all $y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $Ax \leq b$.
But this formulation is problematic because of the non-linear parts $i \cdot g$, $c^\top x$, and $c^\top y$ and because of the for all that results from $\text{ILP}(c) \leq i$.
Am I missing something? Is there a way to reformulate (MaxGap) such that there is any chance of solving it for at least small $n$ and $m$?
Is there any better way for computing the maximal integrality gap?
I think another method would be to find the facet inducing inequalities of the polytope defined by the ILP and compute for each such inequality how much it can be violated by a solution to the LP. However, this approach is also impractical as enumerating facets of an integer polytope is often not possible.
I have cross-posted this question to the cstheory stackexchange.

Can this not be arbitrarily large? Pick a fixed $c$ with optimal solutions $x_{IP} \neq x_{LP}$. Construct $c^\prime = k\cdot c$, and then you have $MAXGAP(c^\prime)=k\cdot MAXGAP(c)$. Maybe I misunderstood, but don't you need to add restrictions to MAXGAP?

There certainly are problems where the integrality gap can be arbitrarily large. But this is not always the case (for example, for vertex cover, the gap is at most 2). Simply scaling $c$ does not work because that would scale LP$(c)$ and ILP$(c)$ equally and this cancels out in the fraction to compute the gap.

Ah of course, sorry for that. Interesting problem!

A tricky problem indeed! While I don't think I have the answer you are looking for, I have some insight into this problem you may find helpful. With that said, let me get to the first point I want to make...
You are very unlikely to avoid the facet enumeration.
To understand why this is the case, we need the following observation about the interaction between the optimal solution and the cost vector:
Proposition 1. Suppose that $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ is a feasible solution of an LP with a feasible set $A\boldsymbol{x}\le b$, and let $I$ be the set of active constraints. Then the set of cost vectors such that $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ is optimal is given by a cone of rows $\boldsymbol{a}_{i,:}, i\in I$.
This statement means that any feasible point $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ has an optimal cone of vectors $\boldsymbol{c} = \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i \boldsymbol{a}_i, \boldsymbol{\lambda} \ge \boldsymbol{0}$ such that $\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c})=\boldsymbol{c}^T \boldsymbol{x}^*$. Now consider a simpler version of your problem where you are looking for a gap between two LPs: $$\max_{\boldsymbol{c}} \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A', \boldsymbol{b}')}. \tag{MaxLPRatio}$$
The key observation here is that if the cost vector $\boldsymbol{c}$ is located on the interior of optimal cones of both LPs, you can shift it to an extreme ray without degrading the (MaxLPRatio) gap.
Lemma 1. Suppose that $\boldsymbol{a}_i, \boldsymbol{a}_j$ and $\boldsymbol{c}=\lambda \boldsymbol{a}_i + \mu \boldsymbol{a}_j, \lambda, \mu > 0$ are in the same optimality cone of both problems, that is, there are points $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ and $\boldsymbol{x}^{**}$ that are optimal for all three cost vectors in $A\boldsymbol{x}\le \boldsymbol{b}$ and $A\boldsymbol{x}' \le \boldsymbol{b}'$ respectively. Then $$\frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{a}_i; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{a}_i; A', \boldsymbol{b}')} \ge \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A', \boldsymbol{b}')} \text{ or } \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{a}_j; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{a}_j; A', \boldsymbol{b}')} \ge \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A', \boldsymbol{b}')}.$$
Proof. Observe that under the assumptions of the lemma we have $$ \frac{\text{LP}(\lambda \boldsymbol{a}_i + \mu \boldsymbol{a}_j; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\lambda \boldsymbol{a}_i + \mu \boldsymbol{a}_j; A', \boldsymbol{b}')} = \frac{\lambda (\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^*) + \mu (\boldsymbol{a}_j^T \boldsymbol{x}^*)}{\lambda (\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**}) + \mu (\boldsymbol{a}_j^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**})}.$$ To complete the proof, you can assume without loss of generality that $\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^{*}/\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**} \ge \boldsymbol{a}_j^T \boldsymbol{x}^{*}/\boldsymbol{a}_j^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**}$ and show that $$\frac{\lambda (\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^*) + \mu (\boldsymbol{a}_j^T \boldsymbol{x}^*)}{\lambda (\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**}) + \mu (\boldsymbol{a}_j^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**})} \le \frac{\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^{*}}{\boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{x}^{**}}$$ by elementary transformations.
Corollary 1. The optimum of (MaxLPRatio) is one of the row vectors of $A$ and $A'$.
Unfortunately, this means that the optimum of (MaxGap) is either a row vector of the original LP or a row vector of the ILP in the denominator – which is exactly the set of facet-defining inequalities.
Fine, but can I still make any progress with that problem?
Yes, but you will have to enumerate both the vertices and the facets, which is hard but doable. Clearly, you can generate cutting planes, extend the set of "candidate" rows, and get increasingly better lower bounds for (MaxGap). While you can exhaustively enumerate all cuts and find the best solution by Corollary 1, you can also speed it up by deriving the upper bounds for (MaxGap) by the following observation:
Proposition 2. Suppose that $A'\boldsymbol{x}\le \boldsymbol{b}'$ is a subset of the convex hull of integer solutions of the original LP. Then $$\frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{ILP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A, \boldsymbol{b})} \le \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A, \boldsymbol{b})}{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}; A', \boldsymbol{b}')}.$$
One way to get an under-approximation required by Proposition 2 is to collect a subset of vertices of the original ILP, construct their convex hull, and solve the corresponding LPs for all row vectors. If the lower and upper bounds are equal (or are within numerical tolerance), you can stop the search; otherwise, you can find a missing vertex, rebuild the convex hull, and solve the linear programs for the new convex hull.
That looks complicated, give me a simpler approach!
Going back to your original problem, you may also see it as a problem of maximizing a continuous function $\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c})/\text{ILP}(\boldsymbol{c})$ over a sphere $\Vert \boldsymbol{c}\Vert_2 = 1$; if that function has also been differentiable, you could employ a projection-based method here, for example, by making a gradient step and normalizing the current $\boldsymbol{c}$ by scaling it by $1/\Vert \boldsymbol{c}\Vert_2$. This function is generally not differentiable, unfortunately, but each of the terms has a subgradient given by the optimal solution of the underlying problem $\boldsymbol{x}^*$; see also the dual ascent subgradient derivation. If you were to "pretend" that this is a genuine gradient expression, you could use it to derive an "identity" $$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{c}} \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c})}{\text{ILP}(\boldsymbol{c})} = \frac{\text{LP}(\boldsymbol{c}) \boldsymbol{x}^*_{\text{ILP}}(\boldsymbol{c})- \text{ILP}(\boldsymbol{c}) \boldsymbol{x}^*_{\text{LP}}(\boldsymbol{c})}{(\text{ILP}(\boldsymbol{c}))^2}$$ and update the cost vector by making the steps along the direction given by the expression above. Unfortunately, this is pointless for any $\boldsymbol{c}$ such that $\boldsymbol{x}^*_{\text{ILP}}(\boldsymbol{c})=\boldsymbol{x}^*_{\text{LP}}(\boldsymbol{c})$ (i.e., the linear relaxation yields an integer solution), so to actually use this approach you would also need to figure out how to come up with "non-trivial" cost vectors given the feasible set.

Damn! Welcome to OR.SE, I suppose :)

Thanks for the insights!
Regarding the gradient descend method: This only finds a local optimum right? Or is there any reason why the function should be convex?

Regarding the facet enumeration approach:
I understand that the largest gap can be found by enumerating all facets. But I am hoping that one can do better because most facets do not lead to large gaps. But I have no idea how to come up with an algorithm that focuses the search onto those facets that lead to large gaps.

@J.Dionisio: thanks!;)

@badboul: (1) "Gradient" descent is indeed a heuristic that finds a local optimum, more specifically, the local optima where the $x_{ILP}$ and $x_{LP}$ are collinear. This is not a convex function because it is the ratio of two convex functions.
(2) Another good question! I would consider either going through the row vectors or looking for thin or thick directions. You may want to ask this separately because a heuristic for good cost vectors would take different insights than a complete algorithm.
